# React Native StackNavigator: Refresh data after goBack() Action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to re-render the first screen of the StackNavigator after saving the data for a new listItem. After a successful save, I call `this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())`
and I want to re-render the page with a a `this._updateData` function. I tried a solution mentioned here: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/922 by beausmith where the `this._updateData` function gets passed to this.props.navigation.navigate like so:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ScreenB', {
  onNavigateBack: this._updateData
})
```

And then  on ScreenB you would do this:

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.onNavigateBack()
```

And

```
this.props.navigation.dispatch(NavigationActions.back())
```

With a StackNavigator, you don't need to call this.props.navigation.navigate, as it is already built into the header. I tried adding `this._updateData` to `this.props.navigation.state.params` in the ComponentDidMount hook of screenA and then calling it as I had above in ScreenB but that didn't seem to do anything (No error message, but no refresh). Any idea where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to only use .back() specifically? why not just navigate to the screen directly this.props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')? Then if you changed state (from user adding a new list item) the component will have already rerendered.

Comment: Hey that worked! I didn't realize that goBack() behaved differently but that makes sense.

Comment: same question give solution ?